# How to escape java regex | operator

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I want to ask something about java regex and hope I will find some help here.

I have a string which looks like `"textX|textY|textZ"`.
Now I want to split this on each `|` character in java.

I tried it with

```
string.split("\|");
```

but I just get a `"Invalid escape sequence"` error.

How can I split the above string when I use `|` as separator?

Comment: backslashes are used to escape metacharaacters

Answer (score 4):

You need double escaping in Java so use:

```
String[] tokens = string.split("\\|")
```

OR else use character class:

```
String[] tokens = string.split("[|]");
```

Comment: Thanks this works. But now i got another problem. The result array should have the same length even if there's no text between the | separators. how can i do this?

Comment: Can you tell me what is your input data and what output you expect?

Answer (score 2):

you should use `\\|` for escaping meta character.

Answer (score 2):

In Java you need to escape characters twice for regex: once for the string, once for the regex.

Try

```
string.split("\\|")
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use double back slash `\\`:  `string.split("\\|")` .

It is because back slash is a escape character for both: java and regex. First one escapses the second for java, so that the "real" backslash is passed to regex.

Answer (score 1):

simply doing

```
string.split("\\|");
```

in java when we escape we do it by two backslashes